# ObjC block in swift

Tags: swift, closures, block

Can anybody help me to rewrite this code in swift

```
    [segmentedControl1 setTitleFormatter:^NSAttributedString *(HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl, NSString *title, NSUInteger index, BOOL selected) {
NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}];
return attString;
}];
```

Part of HMSegmentedControl class:

```
    @interface HMSegmentedControl : UIControl
....
@property (nonatomic, copy) HMTitleFormatterBlock titleFormatter;
....
@end

typedef NSAttributedString *(^HMTitleFormatterBlock)(HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl, NSString *title, NSUInteger index, BOOL selected);
```

My code is:

```
segmentedControl1.titleFormatter = {(segmentedControl: HMSegmentedControl, title: NSString, index: Int, selected: Bool) -> NSAttributedString in

        }
```

I get an error: "‘(HMSegmentedControl, NSString, Int, Bool)->NSAttributedString’ is not convertible to ‘HMTitleFormatterBlock'"

Comment: Can you show the code that declares the `titleFormatter` property?

Comment: It shown above. titleFormatter is property of HMSegmentedControl

Answer (score 3):

yo do a Mix with swift and Objective-C.

```
let titleFormatterBlock: HMTitleFormatterBlock = {(control: AnyObject!, title: String!, index: UInt, selected: Bool) -> NSAttributedString in
            let attString = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()
                ])
            return attString;
        }
segmentedControl.titleFormatter = titleFormatterBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

I have understood my mistake

```
var titleFormatterBlock: HMTitleFormatterBlock = {(control: AnyObject!, title: String!, index: UInt, selected: Bool) -> NSAttributedString in
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}];
    return attString;
}
segmentedControl.titleFormatter = titleFormatterBlock
```

Comment: So what was your mistake?